# CSS is not loaded at all in Internet Explorer (SEC7113)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have an AngularJS Website, which works perfectly in every browser. But in Internet Explorer (tested with version 11) CSS is not loaded at all.

**Error Code**: SEC7113

**Error Message**: "CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch"

Also check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180764(v=vs.85).aspx

This is how I include my CSS (right before ):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
```

Also This is my Doctype:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
```

I know for sure (100%), that it worked in Internet Explorer few weeks ago, since I tested the performance in different browser. Since then, the css changed a lot. But not the way I include the CSS.

Does anybody know, what could be the problem here? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the http header provided by the sever? You can see that in the network tab of thr developers tools.

Comment: Answer HTTP/1.1 200 OK ........
Server websocket-sharp/1.0 ........
Date Mon, 15 Dec 2014 18:05:50 GMT ........
Transfer-Encoding chunked ........
Keep-Alive timeout=15,max=88 ........  I added the points, so its easier to read.

Comment: Huh? Is the css coming over a websocket? That is weird.... (and you know you can [edit] your post?)

Comment: Im using Websockets in my AngularJS-Site, but the CSS is loaded via http: http://localhost:8080/css/app.css

Comment: You did not post the `Content-type` header in the previous comment. If it is actually missing from the headers, consider adding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is with an invalid mime-type for the CSS file. It's possible your CSS file is actually being sent down with a mime-type like `text/plain` instead of `text/css`. As a result, Internet Explorer  prevents the file from loading so as to avoid potential attack vectors.

This problem was most notably seen when people would reference JavaScript files from GitHub, which are served with `text/plain` mime-types, but inteded to be used as `text/javascript` in the document.

Ensure that your response headers contain the `text/css` mime-type and you should be fine. This information is available in the F12 Developer Tools under the *Network* panel.

[image]

Comment: Note that a reference to the error codes reported by the IE11 console can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423949(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Thank you very much. The webserver was not returning the correct mime-types. Now its working fine in IE too. Thank you very much! :)