# AngularJS css styles lost when reloading page with parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an AngularJS page using UI router for routing. My problem is that when I reload a page with a parameter the css stylesheet is lost :(

The css file is referenced in my index.html like:

```
<link href="Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And my route config looks like:

```
  .state('member', {
        url: '/member/:userId',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/member.html',
                controller: 'memberController'
            }
        },
        data: {
            access: 'access.user'
        }
    })
```

I also have html5mode(true) if thats make a difference. I have googled a lot without finding anyone else having this problem which leads me to the conclusion that I have completely misunderstood something :) Anyone who can point me in the right direction here?

Comment: The html5Mode exactly make the difference!! ;) ;) I would say, that this should be solved by propert `<base href="/"` setting... because that is changing from browser perspective on your REFRESH...

Comment: I think that this is more to do with that `templateUrl` prepend it with a `/` so  it looks like  `templateUrl: '/app/views/member.html',` if you don't I believe it will be a relative path rather than an absolute.

Comment: `html5Mode(true)` is for turning off hash URLs, i.e. not looking like this: `http://examplesite.com/#/member`

Comment: Thanks guys! Unfortunately neither of your suggestions worked, I already have the base setting in my index file and the addition of slash before the templateurl does not solve the problem :( Reloading works perfectly fine for all parameterless views.

Comment: Create a plnkr to replicate

Comment: Well I tried to create a simple plnkr [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/X26nvcz9r1DVxjBj0Wkb?p=preview) now but for some reason the views does not show when I add base href and html5Mode(true)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar problem. I have always lost me stylesheets on refresh.
I have tried to load the page in IE and seen some warnings I haven't seen in Chrome:

```
SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch
File: reset.min.css
```

Link for SEC7113: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180764(v=vs.85).aspx

-> check to make sure your css in the head are included this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
```

need to include type="text/css"

This also led me here: [CSS is not loaded at all in Internet Explorer (SEC7113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490193/css-is-not-loaded-at-all-in-internet-explorer-sec7113)
and after examining my  requests, I've found that the url of my style sheets was

```
viewName/css/reset.css
```

so I have changed my  includes to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/reset.css">
```

(additional slash on the start of the address to css) and all worked again ...

so in your case is should be

```
<link href="/Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Hope this help.