# Images, css not loading after session timeout on login screen page load.

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am adding a check for session timeout and added this code to the web.config file.

```
<deny users = "?">
```

and it works and redirects users to the login page when the session expires. When I build the project from Visual Studio the first time, its missing the images and css files. Here is the warning I am seeing in the console.

```
CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch
```

When I remove the deny users code it works as expected. I am not sure why this would cause any issues. Does it have something to do with users not being able to access the content since its denied? What would be the best way to handle this issue?

I have tried adding Sessionstate

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="1">
<providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
 </providers>
</sessionState>
```

and

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
</modules>
```

to the config file and it does not fix the issue. I also verified that the static content is hosted in IIS. Any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: What mime type is the CSS being served as? (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27491483/43846)

Comment: text/html and this is the url: http://localhost/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx

Comment: Why are you serving CSS as `text/html` rather than `text/css`? As you are denying access to all unauthenticated users, you need to allow ALL users access to the path of your CSS and Images.

Comment: No, my reference to the css file is text/css not text/html. Once I login I can see the css file as text/css not text/html which is weird. I think it has something to do with denying users access. I tried adding access to css and images too but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason it is giving you a mime type mismatch is because when you request the css file or images the server is responding with your login screen because they are not authenticated. Something like this:

Browser requests CSS File -> Not Authenticated -> Cancel Request -> Respond with login screen

To fix this you need to allow unauthenticated access to your static resources.

**Deny access to unauthenticated users**

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

**Allow access to css/images for unauthenticated users**

```
<location path="App_Themes/Default/DefaultStyleSheet.css">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The location path attribute can either be the path to a single file or add to the folder where they are all stored. Alternatively, you can add a web.config file to the folder that contains your css/images.

Comment: What do you get if you go to the css file in a browser when you are **not logged in**? If you see the login screen then you haven't allowed access to unauthenticated users.

Comment: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch and http://localhost/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fApp_Themes%2fDefault%2fDefaultStyleSheet.css

Comment: That's what I would expect, you haven't correctly allowed access to the css file for unauthenticated users. I have updated my answer with the actual path to your css file. If you use this code and test browsing to the css file it should now work.

Comment: This is a weird problem as I still cant get it to work. I have tried chrome and IE. No errors though.

Comment: I am adding all this to my project web.config. Will it have to be another web.config files in the css directory?

Comment: The problem with my code was the ~/ . I changed the path to App-Themes/Default/DefaultStyleSheet.css and its working now on both Chrome and IE. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried and it seems to work on Chrome but not IE. Will need to do more testing but here is my latest changes

```
<location path="~/Account/Login">
    <system.web>
         <authorization>
             <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

and added  to the authorization for session timeout check.